# Importing CSV into database using Python

Tags: python, csv

I'm trying to import a csv file into a connecting MySQL database using python. However, I keep getting the following error: ProgrammingError: not enough arguments for format string.

All code runs perfect until: "cursor.execute(" Does anybody have any ideas?

Code used:

```
#Python connect with SQL
import MySQLdb
import csv
import sys

conn = MySQLdb.connect(host="127.0.0.1", user="root", password="", database="furniture")

print ("Connected with database")

cursor = conn.cursor()
csv_data = csv.reader(open(r"C:\Users\M.schuurman\Downloads\furniture2.csv"))
header = next(csv_data)

print('Importing the CSV Files')

for row in csv_data:
    print(row)
    cursor.execute(
        "INSERT INTO customer (customerid, customername, pcnumbers, pcletters, street,  number, province) VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s)", row)

conn.commit()
cursor.close()
print('Done')
```

Comment: Maybe `row` hasn't got enough values to fill all the fields?

Comment: It look like Your row is a single string convert it to tuple

Comment: @Osama It's the output of a `csv.reader`, so it's already a list or tuple.

Comment: try len(row) before insert statement

Answer (score 0):

Check the values of `csv_data` variable with `print(list(csv_data))` or better with `print(repr(row))` if `csv_data` is an iterator or the dataset is large.

As mentioned in the comment, the `row` does not have enough values to fill the `%s` placeholders of `execute()` function and will fail.

Here's more details on what's happening - the `mysqlclient`'s [`cursors.BaseCursor.execute()`](https://github.com/PyMySQL/mysqlclient/blob/5340191feb16b1f99a7b43fe7c74a2f690138cb1/MySQLdb/cursors.py#L201) attempts a `"templated string %s, %s" % ("one value", )` which will raise a `TypeError` that gets renamed into [`ProgrammingError`](https://github.com/PyMySQL/mysqlclient/blob/5340191feb16b1f99a7b43fe7c74a2f690138cb1/MySQLdb/cursors.py#L203).

```
>>> "templated string %s, %s" % ("one value", )
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: not enough arguments for format string
```

and due to the count of placeholders (`%s`) being greater than the count of values for formating/templating the `TypeError` is raised.